any reason why patents for dating apps are mainly local to the US?
I've seen many patents for dating apps, even from big companies like Match Group. They are mainly local to the USA.
At the very minimum, I would expect them to also file in Europe and China?
Those are huge markets.
So, any reason why they don't claim at least those markets?

Given Europe’s stricter criteria for software patents, dating apps might struggle to meet the “technical character” requirement, as many focus on matchmaking algorithms or user interactions, which are often considered abstract or business-related. This could deter companies from pursuing patents in Europe, where success is less certain compared to the U.S.

What about China, is it also harder there for software patents?

Yes and no. It's similar to EU but a little less restrictive:
https://www.epo.org/en/service-support/faq/searching-patents/asian-patent-information/china/general-information-about-3
For US see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_Corp._v._CLS_Bank_International

@PatentDev Welcome to Ask Patents. Thanks for the answer.
